# Override CSS table formatting

Tags: html, css, overriding

I use the following CSS to apply a top border to the last-child row of various tables:

```
.mytabs tr:last-child {
border-top:1px solid #000;
font-weight:bold;}
```

Now what I need to do is to override this style for one particular table.  How can I override this style in one specific instance?  Thanks.

Comment: Give that particular table an ID and select that ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap it a custom div id name example `<div id="customFormat"></div>` or give the table an id `<table id="customFormat"></table>`

In CSS, you can specify the custom styling just for that 1 table.

```
#customFormat { 
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(69,54,37,0.2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I will give it a try now and let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 1):

Give a class specific table or to the last row of specific table and apply style

```
table.<specific_table> tr:last-child {
...your style
}
```

or

```
.mytabs tr.<specific_row> {
..your style}
```