# Shiny: Format tables differently

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am trying to develop a shiny app in which I will need to create several tables differently formated.

I am currently using a css file as a theme to control the basic format of my application but this will affect all tables in the app in the same way. How could I assign a specific css file to a table with a paricular id.

I have also found this particular topic: [Override CSS table formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707481/override-css-table-formatting) which addresses the issue within an html context and as I am relatively new to css I would appreciate some help in a shiny/r context.

I assume that if there is a solution which related a css file with  the id of the a table in a similar fashion someone could apply the same concept in every shiny element that can be formated via css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need a seperate css file. You can have multiple styling in the same file targetting different elements.
You would target the table using its unique id. In CSS id is designated using `#` so `#mytable` refers to styling for the element with `id=mytable`. In your CSS style file you could have for example:

```
#mytable tr td { 
someattribute: somevalue;
}
```

this would style the table cells of the table with `id=mytable`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this and for many more concize answers you have also given me in the past.